xmlstarlet. Change multiple values in several lines to 1 line with values separated with "---". Is it possible?
I have this xml file ( truncated)
<adddata dn="articulo">
<attr name="code">
<value>34839473</value>
<value>12263522</value>
</attr>
</adddata>

I want to update / replace multivalued lines to 1 with values separated with "---". Like this:
<attr name="code">
<value>34839473---12263522</value>
</attr>

I tried:
xmlstarlet ed -u "//attr[@name='code']" -x 'concat(value[1], "---", value[2])'`

and result in:
<attr name="code">2312341---2348444</attr>

but i dont know how to include "<value>" and "</value>" in the line
Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance

If there are no more than 2 value elements it can be done with
straight XPath using the following-sibling axis.
With less than 2 values only the document formatting may change,
with more than 2 only the first 2 are modified.
# shellcheck shell=sh disable=SC2016

xmlstarlet edit -O \
  --var A '/*/attr[@name="code"]' \
  -u '$A/value[1][following-sibling::value]' \
  -x 'concat(.,"---",following-sibling::value)' \
  -d '$A/value[2]' \
file.xml


In case there are more than 2 value elements it can be done using
the EXSLT str:concat function which can handle
an entire node-set (the XPath 1.0 string
functions ignore all but the first member of a node-set).
This will work correctly with 0, 1, 2, or more value elements.
# shellcheck shell=sh disable=SC2016

xmlstarlet edit -O \
  --var A '/*/attr[@name="code"]' \
  -a '$A/value[position()!=last()]' -t elem -n value -v '---' \
  --var V '$A/value' \
  -u '$V[1]' -x 'str:concat($V)' \
  -d '$V[position()!=1]' \
file.xml


-a (aka --append) inserts a separator after each value
except the last
variable V collects all the values (previous and new) in a node-set
the first value element is updated with the concatenated
string values
-d deletes all values except the first

Recall that xmlstarlet edit processes its actions in order and that
it reads from and writes to one document tree, unlike an XSLT 1.0
processor which reads from a source tree and writes to a separate
result tree.
Side note: xmlstarlet edit supports these EXSLT
string functions: str:align, str:concat, str:decode-uri,
str:encode-uri, and str:padding;
the select and transform subcommands also str:replace,
str:split, and str:tokenize.
